# How do I pipe formula-driven data to multiple lines in a single cell?

Tags: excel

Excel allows you to enter multiple lines of data into a single cell by pressing Alt + Enter every time you wish to start a new line.

Unfortunately, it appears that there is no way to do this for data driven through a formula.

I am trying to simply pipe data from multiple cells to multiple lines within a single cell.

If I had the following data:

```
A     B     C     D     E
1    Mr.  David  Pho
2    Mr.  Lenny Ancio
```

I try to use the following formula with no luck.

=B1&" "&C1&" "&D1

=B2&" "&C2&" "&D2

I have also tried adding the ACII code for a carriage return, but that does not seem to work either.

Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `Char(10)` for a line break within a cell's formula.

**Note:** that you *MUST* have the cell's 'Wrap text' proprty set to true.

To use your example, it would be:

```
=B1 & Char(10) & C1 & Char(10) & D1
```